# jQuery errors during Ember Bootstrap-Switch checkedbox data binding

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, coffeescript

I am attempting to use Bootstrap-Switch in an Ember project.

I have read a lot of other SO posts, blogs, and issues and have come up empty. I've gotten farther than I've been able to in the last day, but now I'm running into what seems like a scope issue.

hasChanged method of my ToggleView is where the meat of the problem is.

```
App.ToggleView = Ember.View.extend(
  classNames: ['switch']

  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked disabled=disabled}}'

  afterRenderEvent: ->
    self = this
    @$("[type='checkbox']").on "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", @hasChanged
    @$("[type='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('animate', false)
    @$("[type='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('size', 'small')

  hasChanged: (e, data) ->
    @set "checked", data
    #console.log data
    return
)
```

The commented out `console.log` prints out the correct state of the switch. However, the console complains regarding the `@set`. (space added because I can't figure out escaping this html at the moment)

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #< HTMLInputElement> has no method 'set'

I have tried replacing that line with `@set "checked", @$("[type='checkbox']").prop("checked")`, but that just gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #< HTMLInputElement> has no method '$'

Here is how I'm attempting to use this view.

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="form-inline pull-right">
    <div>
      <label>Enable Notifications {{view App.ToggleView id="notificationsToggle" controller=controller}}</label>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Notification Settings</h2>
</div>
{{isChecked}} {{disabled}}

App.NotificationsController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  isChecked: true
  disabled: false

  isCheckedChanged: (->
    isChecked = @get('isChecked')
    console.log isChecked
  ).observes('isChecked')
)
```

This ALL functions perfectly if I comment out the afterRenderEvent and just don't use bootstrap-switch. My data binds. My controller isCheckedChanged fires. It's great.

Thoughts?

**For reference**

I have this code block in another portion of the project to allow me to override a method to run jQuery requests after any view has rendered.

```
Ember.View.reopen(
  didInsertElement: ->
    @_super()
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce "afterRender", this, @afterRenderEvent
    return

  afterRenderEvent: ->
)
```

**UPDATE**

I solved my scope problem by making replacing `hasChanged` with an anonymous function. (At least I think that's why.)

Other than that, removing `isCheckedChanged` and setting the controller's `isChecked` simply required me to set up a reference to the view's controller, and it all functions.

Thanks so much, Chuck!

Updated Controller

```
App.NotificationsController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  isChecked: true
  disabled: false
)
```

Updated View

```
App.ToggleView = Ember.View.extend(
  classNames: ['switch']
  controller = @controller

  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked disabled=disabled}}'

  afterRenderEvent: ->
    self = this

    @$("input[type='checkbox']").on "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", (e, data) ->
      self.controller.set "isChecked", data
    @$("[type='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('animate', false)
    @$("[type='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('size', 'small')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not a coffeeScript guy, but it seems as though your isCheckedChanged observer is setting isChecked to it's own value. so it would never change.

It would seem as though you need to set controller.isChecked from your hasChanged handler in the view.

so... (I don't know coffeescript so I'm taking a stab at what changes you'd need below)

```
App.ToggleView = Ember.View.extend(
  classNames: ['switch']

  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked disabled=disabled}}'

  afterRenderEvent: ->
    self = this
    @$("[type='checkbox']").on "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", @hasChanged
    @$("[type='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('animate', false)
    @$("[type='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('size', 'small')

  hasChanged: (e, data) ->
    controller@set "isChecked", data
    #console.log data
    return
)
```

Then you should probably remove the isCheckedChanged observer as it looks like it could be stuck in a loop.

Comment: Posting an update based on this. This was so helpful! Thanks, Chuck.